# How to checkout custom source code branch in TFS 18 build task

Tags: github, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

Based on the variable value defined before the CI pipeline is kicked off, I want to decide which branch of the code from the git repository should be selected. Any idea how can this be done?
[Screenshot of build step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hWay.png)

Comment: What specific difficulties are you encountering? The branch to checkout can be selected when the build is queued.

Comment: I am trying to have an automated build definition made for building a solution and running tests in certain environment. Based on the environment which is defined in the variable section, I want my build definition to check out branch corresponding to that environment without any manual interference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch to checkout can be selected when the build is queued. You do not need to do anything special to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to have an automated build definition created for building a solution and running tests targeting certain environment. Based on the environment which is defined in the variable section, I want my build definition to check out branch corresponding to that environment without any manual interference.